# How do I visit a list of urls one after the other?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to create an automatic way to load url after url sequentially and save the resource found at each url to a folder.

Jdownloader can't seem to notice the resource at the url so I've tried various javascript options.

```
<script>
var i = 100;
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
    async function demo() {
while (i < 330) {
  window.location = "https://ia601708.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/10/items/sexualsuicide00gild/sexualsuicide00gild_jp2.zip&file=sexualsuicide00gild_jp2/sexualsuicide00gild_0"+i+".jp2&scale=1&rotate=0";
  console.log('Taking a break...');
  await sleep(5000);
  console.log('Two seconds later');
  i++;
      }
}
demo();
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
var i = 100;
while (i < 330) {
window.location = "https://ia601708.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/10/items/sexualsuicide00gild/sexualsuicide00gild_jp2.zip&file=sexualsuicide00gild_jp2/sexualsuicide00gild_0"+i+".jp2&scale=1&rotate=0";
$(window).bind("load", function() {
i++;
});
}
</script>
```

I thought I'd be able to just loop url requests, iterate the url names by one, load the resource, then automatically load the next url in the sequence and then just later save the accumulated cache. But no, all the loops I've tried just freeze my browser. I'm surprised such a simple task is so difficult.

Comment: `window.location` will redirect you to that page/resource. Why do you think that the javascript on page X will run on page Y?

Comment: makes sense. so i should open the url in an iframe?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? To download the resources at those urls using javascript or to simply open them up on new tabs?

Comment: I ended up just using autohotkey.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and then parse the HTML response using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) or use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to get the DOM object for the pages you're scraping. Then you can use query selectors to find the next URL you want to scrape and save the current one (or any external reference from it) as file blobs.

Depending on the target host, you might run into CORS restrictions that would prevent you from accessing the response contents. For this and other reasons it's more common to use Node.js for writing scrapers, because they're not restricted by CORS policies and you have direct access to the file system for storage.